# Function define a new object class

Tags: r, function, object

is it possible to define a new object class for a output of my function, e.g:

```
newclass <- function(text) {
  output <- strsplit(text,split="")[[1]]
  output
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's even very simple. Just assign the value using `class<-`.

```
newclass <- function(text) {
  output <- strsplit(text,split="")[[1]]
  class(output) <- "toby"
  output
}

x <- newclass("rui")
class(x)
[1] "toby"
x
[1] "r" "u" "i"
attr(,"class")
[1] "toby"
```